# If arrays in C++ require a size that is a constant expression, why can I use a variable with just const to initialize it?

Tags: arrays, c++11

I was reading about how in C++ array sizes require a constant expression, it must be evaluated at compile time.

Then I learned that things labled `const` are not evaluated at compile time, and `const` acts as a read only.

Why am I allowed to do something like this:

```
const int x = 5;
int myarray[x] = {};
```

This compiles in Visual Studio 2015. Why doesn't `x` have to be `constexpr`?

Comment: "I learned that things labled const are not evaluated at compile time, and const acts as a read only." - you learned wrong. Please reconsider the usefulness of wherever you read that

Comment: It was actually here on SO. Could you clarify const for me?

Comment: It would be good to provide a link to said material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on *context*. In the context you show the "variable" `x` *is* a compile-time constant, because the compiler can create is as such.

If, on the other hand, you have something like

```
void f(const int x)
{
    int myarray[x] = {};
    ...
}
```

Then that won't work because `x` is no longer a compile-time constant, but a run-time constant.

Comment: I tried putting the `const int` in the scope of `main()` along with the array and it still compiled. Is there some sort of rule that compilers will use to determine if a `const` variable is a `constexpr`? In other words, in what context will the compiler create it as such?

Comment: @Dillydill123 [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). Point 10(a) of "core constant expressions" in particular

Comment: @Dillydill123 Besides the formal rules (pointed out by M.M) as a general rule of thumb you could in a simplified way say that if you initialize a `const` variable then it's a compile-time constant.

Comment: If you get rid of the "...", your code will compile.